# Download various kind of file from web api in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have an application where i am required to download file from web api to client script(javascript). The file can be of any type like pdf, doc, txt or jpg and its storing in SQL database in varBinary format. I am executing below code and its downloading the file but always show file as corrupt. In case of txt file, its simply showing byte array as a text in the downladed txt file.
Following are the code

```
var row; // object from web api

 var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
  var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(row.result.ContentData)], { type: row.result.ContentType });
  anchor.attr({
            href: window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
            target: '_blank',
            download: row.result.BlogName + '.' + row.result.format 
        })[0].click();
```

Comment: various kind of file you need to define a type somewhere so it can b process accordingly

Comment: @NegiRox File type is irrelevant if you just download it and store it as binary data in a database.

Comment: yes but if you are storing it in SQL, so somewhere you are fetching your file you need to create file according to your need.